# how to transform json into beans when msg received from the queue

Tags: java, apache-camel

Java 8 Apache camel

I have camel route which listens to the active MQ. my queue contains the JSON payload. i have crated the mapper bean wondering how can i convert json response into list of mapper objects.

```
from ("activemq:queue:my.queue")
.log("msg received").log("body" + ${body}");

class myMapper{
String name; 
String addr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to review the [Camel JSON](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) page and associated example. Converting from JSON text -> Java object is referred to as 'unmarshalling' in Camel, and Java Object -> JSON text is 'marshalling'.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ("activemq:queue:my.queue")
.log("msg received")
.unmarshal().json(Jackson, MyMapper.class).to("sendToAnotherRoute");
```